# proxy cross domain requests with angular --proxy.config

Tags: angular

On the development machine I am sending request from `http://localhost:4200` to `https://example.com`. In production, I am sending requests from  `https://app.example.com` to `https://example.com`.  I need to pass cookies for backend to recognise my local machine as authorized.

This is the `proxy.conf.json` contents I tried, but no cookies were sent as validated by backend server:

```
{
  "example.com/api/**": {
    "target": "https://example.com/",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "headers": {"Cookie":"PHPSESSID=session_id_here"}
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "/api/**": {
    "target": "https://example.com/",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "headers": {"Cookie":"PHPSESSID=session_id_here"}
  }
}
```

I am using absolute path for http requests as in `httpClient.get("https://example.com/api/something").subscribe(()=>{})`

I build with:

```
 ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --proxy-config="proxy.conf.json"
```

Is is possible to append headers when performing cross origin requests with angular `--proxy-config` cli option? I had success with relative same domain requests (localhost:4200 to localhost:4200 gets proxied successfully), but none with absolute cross domain requests. I realize this is highly unlikely to be possible with `--proxy.config`. What are the alternative options?

Answer (score 0):

I solved if by using environment.production variable:

```
  public prefixUrl = "https://example.com";
  private serverDataUrl = (environment.production ? this.prefixUrl : "")+ "/api/path";
```

and the following config for --proxy.config

```
{
  "/api/**": {
    "target": "https://example.com/",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "headers": {"Cookie":"PHPSESSID=session_id_here"}
  }
}
```

It is a bit limited, but it works fine as along as requests are made only to single domain with path that starts with /api.